# firebase snapshot changes when loading the same screen multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project, I can click on other users profiles. When the profile opens I check whether the user is public and whether they are friends. This is done with these Methods which are inside of the `User` class

```
func areTheyFriends(user: User, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("friends").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        print("the friends snapshot = \(snapshot)")
        if snapshot.hasChild(user.uid) {
            completion(true)
        }
        else{
            completion(false)
        }
    }

}

func checkIfPublic(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("publicProfile").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        let profile = snapshot.value as? Bool
        completion(profile!)

    }
}
```

the first method will observe the currentUsers friends and see if the user is in that snapshot. The second method will check if the user is public or not.

These methods are called in a class called `FriendsProfileTableViewController` as so:

```
func checkIfPublic(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    self.user.checkIfPublic { (isPublic) in
        if isPublic == true {

            print("the user is public")
            completion(isPublic)

        }else if isPublic == false{

            print("the user is private")
            completion(isPublic)

        }
    }

}

func checkIfFriends(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    currentUser.areTheyFriends(user: user) { (areFriends) in
        if areFriends == false {

            print("users are not friends")
            completion(areFriends)


        }else if areFriends == true{

            print("the users are friends")
            completion(areFriends)
        }
    }

}
```

I call them in `viewWillAppear`

```
checkIfPublic { (isPublic) in
            self.checkIfFriends { (areFriends) in

                if (isPublic == true) && (areFriends == false) {
                    //is the user is public but are not friends
                    self.setPageIfNotFriends()
                }
                if (isPublic == false) && (areFriends == false) {
                    //if the user is private and they are not friends
                    self.profileIsPrivateAndNotFriends()
                }

                if (areFriends == true) {
                    self.setPageIfFriends()
                }
            }
        }
```

If the user is **public** and the two users **aren't friends** then I set the page up as so with an add friend button. However, if the user is **private** and the two users **aren't friends** then I dismiss the page with this method:

```
func profileIsPrivateAndNotFriends(){

    self.popup.showUnsuccessfullAlert(message: "You cannot view this profile. You and \(self.user.firstName) are not friends")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

The problem that I have is for example, the current user

```
users --
    vreBtOydi2e2DbPxQBdKBhoN1c82 --
        birthday: "09/06/1996"
        firstName: "Beth"
        friends --
            BgwmyThLOuhmzwsaCvM0Z6ILDNn1: true
        lastName: "jones" 
        publicProfile: true
        uid: "vreBtOydi2e2DbPxQBdKBhoN1c82"
```

and user2:

```
users --
        BgwmyThLOuhmzwsaCvM0Z6ILDNn1 --
            birthday: "14/03/1995"
            firstName: "Andrew"
            friends --
                vreBtOydi2e2DbPxQBdKBhoN1c82: true
            lastName: "Harris" 
            publicProfile: false
            uid: "BgwmyThLOuhmzwsaCvM0Z6ILDNn1"
```

Both users are friends, so when I click on the user2 profile I get to see the profile and everything is fine, in the console when `areTheyFriends` runs, this shows up:

```
the friends snapshot = Snap (friends) {
BgwmyThLOuhmzwsaCvM0Z6ILDNn1 = 1;
}
```

which is the snapshot for the current user's friends. However, when I navigate through the user2 profile, I can click onto one of their lists which brings up a new page of their lists. From here I can click onto the user2 name which takes me to their profile again. Like so:

[image]

this time though the snapshot looks a little different:

```
the friends snapshot = Snap (friends) {
vreBtOydi2e2DbPxQBdKBhoN1c82 = 1;
}
```

the snapshot is showing the user2 friends even though I never call that. And obviously, it thinks we arent friends because the snapshot does not `hasChild` of user2 uid and so the `profileIsPrivateAndNotFriends()` method gets called.

Does anyone know what is going wrong and why when the profile page gets shown more than once that the snapshot changes? The database never changes during this time. Thank you

Comment: You've done a good job explaining the issue, however there are bits of code missing. For example, where is the code that executes when Andrew Harris taps his name to 'go back to' the main Andrew Harris view that has his lists. What code populates that list and what code is used to set the User properties. My guess is you're overwriting the User at some point so the initial user is being replaced by the user clicked on. Remember it's important to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without hitting us with a wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the "user" variable of areTheyFriends() being set when segue-ing between views? It might be that it's not being set the second time, so the boolean closure for areTheyFriends will always return false.

Comment: I kept on thinking it was to do with the user and current user being swapped since the snapshot was showing that but I couldn't find where until you commented this. I checked where I passed the data from the profile to the listing detail and I had accidentally passed the user object into the current user variable. I changed it to the correct variable and it is fixed. Such a stupid mistake, I thought it was more complicated than this. Thank you for your help